# show status and restart wso2 from a webpage

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have my wso2 servers up and running..now customer came up with a rewuirement that they need a separate webpage [ofcourse authenitucated] where they can see the status [up/down] and they would like to stop and start wso2 from that page rather than going to wso2 admin console.
Is there any API for getting the status as well as stopping/starting of wso2 ? 
My product is wso2 EI
I guess I can invoke the wso2server.bat from Java and achieve is..is this ideal to do that or are there other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WSO2 admin services to check the server(each node) status, do server restart or put into maintenance mode as well.

This internal admin service is called `ServerAdmin` and it's running on the servlet port(9443 - https://localhost:9443/services/ServerAdmin ). Below are the few operations available on that service

- isAlive
- restartGracefully
- startMaintenance
- endMaintenance

If you want to check the WSDL of this service, you need to change the visibility of admin WSDLs using `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` configuration in the carbon.xml file.

Comment: For restarting the server,is this better than invoking the wso2sever script from java?are there any advantages with this?